# drop logins from SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

I stacked here when I try to drop logins from sql server 2000
I used this script to get all the lists before dropping the logins, after I got all the lists I tried to execute the outputs, like "Drop login [xxxxx]" but got this error messages.

```
“Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'LOGIN'.”
```

The Script as follow

```
----------Script Begin--------
CREATE TABLE #sid (sid binary(85) NOT NULL)

INSERT #sid (sid)
 EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'select sid from sysusers WHERE sid IS NOT NULL'

SELECT 'DROP LOGIN ' + quotename(name)
 FROM   master.dbo.syslogins l
 WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM   #sid s
                    WHERE  s.sid = l.sid)
 AND name NOT LIKE '##%'
 AND name NOT LIKE 'NT %'

go
 DROP TABLE #sid
----------Script ends--------
```

Please help me out
Am newbie for sql server
Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: use exec sp_dropuser [userName] and exec sp_droplogin [loginName] instead

Answer (score 2):

SQL 2000 code to drop a login:

```
EXEC master..sp_revokelogin @loginame='YOURDOMAIN\xxxxx'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what SSMS generated for SQL 2000. Funny thing is, there is different code for domain and SQL logins.

**Domain login:**

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_revokelogin @loginame = N'your_domain\login'
```

**SQL login:**

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_droplogin @loginame = N'sql_login'
```